# How to execute a string by replacing a comma with single quote comma single quote in SQL dynamic query

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I have written dynamic query.
If I execute replace it shows an error

```
DECLARE @C VARCHAR(500)
    SET @C  = ' DECLARE @P VARCHAR(20) ' + 
              ' SET @P=''a,b'' ' +
              '  ''''''+ REPLACE(@P,'','','''''','''''')+''''
  print @c
  exec(@C)
```

The normal query is

```
DECLARE @P VARCHAR(20)  
    SET @P='a,b' 
     print '''' + REPLACE(@P,',',''',''')+''''
```

It was executed correctly. While in dynamic query its throw an error

Comment: What does the error message says ?

Comment: And what is the result of `print(@c)`? (And do you even need dynamic SQL?)

Comment: Consider using `sp_executesql` to pass in parameters properly

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need Dynamic SQL for that query ?
In the meantime, correct it for you, you missed some "'"

```
DECLARE @C VARCHAR(500)
    SET @C  = ' DECLARE @P VARCHAR(20) ' + 
              ' SET @P=''a,b'' ' +
              ' PRINT '''''''' + REPLACE(@P,'','','''''','''''')+'''''''''
  print @c
  exec(@C)
```